# Is memory or storage in the 2018 Mac mini replaceable by the user after purchase?

Tags: mac, ssd, upgrade, memory, mac-mini

The [tech specs](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/) of the [Mac mini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini) 2018 is unclear if the [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) or [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) can be upgraded by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a guide on [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+mini+Late+2018+Memory+Replacement/115309), summarized on MacRumors.com: [*2018 Mac mini Teardown: User-Upgradeable RAM, But Soldered Down CPU and Storage*](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/11/09/ifixit-mac-mini-2018-teardown/)

## Memory: Yes*

Apple specifically mentions on the Apple Website that the Memory are SO-DIMM sockets (2666MHz [DDR4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) [SO-DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM)).

> Mac mini features high-performance 2666MHz DDR4 SO-DIMM memory

*However, the warranty is voided if upgraded by the user as the modules are no longer directly accessible from the bottom but instead involve removing the antenna plate, fan and mainboard.

## Storage: No

Storage is (like on the MacBooks) soldered onto the logic board and therefor non-replaceable (you would need to replace the entire logic board).

Answer (score 3):

You’ll need to wait for someone like iFixit to get one and do a teardown to be sure, but since they made a big deal in the presentation of it using SO-DIMMs it is very likely that the memory is user-upgradable. The SSD is probably not officially upgradable, but we’ll have to wait and see if it actually can be removed and replaced or if it’s part of the motherboard.

Edited to add: This review from Tom’s guide confirms that the RAM is upgradable with difficulty (it’s only intended to be upgraded by Apple, not by the user) but the SSD is soldered to the motherboard and can’t be upgraded. https://www.tomsguide.com/us/mac-mini,review-5908.html

Comment: I've removed all the comments. Please keep in mind that up/downvotes are the primary method of approving of/disliking an answer, and that any answer driving the topic forward is welcome on the site (even if it may get outdated over time).

Answer (score 1):

## Apple says: RAM is *not* user-installable on Mac mini (2018)

While I do not know what this means in terms of voiding the warranty…

Apple does *not* consider the RAM in a Mac mini (2018) to be user-installable.

The Apple Support page [*Upgrade or install memory in your Mac mini*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205041) says:

> **2018**
>
> Mac mini (2018) does not have user-installable RAM. You can configure the memory in your Mac mini (2018) when you purchase it. To upgrade the memory in your Mac mini (2018), go to an Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this article https://uk.pcmag.com/apple-logic-pro-x-for-mac/118215/hands-on-apple-finally-updates-the-mac-mini says that the SSD is not user replaceable but it looks like the RAM potentially will be.

Comment: Lots of parts that Apple don't formally claim to be user-replaceable can in fact be replaced by an ambitious users who doesn't mind voiding their warranty. It remains to be seen if the new Mac Mini SSD falls into that category or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with an Apple employee with the Chat Support and confirm that SSD is soldered and not user-replaceable. so buy the storage you need from the beginning...